# Which of the following sentences is more natural and grammatically correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which of the following sentences is more natural and grammatically correct?

> 1. Without their having been read, the books were returned to the library.
> 2. Without having been read, the books were returned to the library.
> 3. Without being read, the books were returned to the library.

Comment: All of the sentences are more complicated than they need to be. If you want natural, try "The books were returned to the library unread".